# MacOs change the version of ruby installed via brew

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, homebrew

[image]

I have `ruby` that was installed via `brew`, I updated the version via `brew`, but I can't change the default version being used.

Can you give me a hand?

Edit:

I installed `rbenv` next, I didn't have any version manager for ruby.

I installed version `3.2.2` via rbenv, here are the steps:

```
brew install rbenv 
rbenv install 3.2.2
rbenv use 3.2.2
```

When I check the version I have I get this:

[image]

If on the terminal `echo $PATH` I get this:

```
/Users/userName/.bun/bin:
/Users/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.17.1/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/Library/TeX/texbin:
/Library/Apple/usr/bin:
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:
/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:
/Users/userName/.maestro/bin
```

Comment: Why don't use Ruby manager, for example one of these: asdf, rvm, rbenv, chruby?

Comment: He probably IS using a version manager and forgetting (not realizing?!). That'd explain how he can update ruby with brew but still have the PATH ruby at 2.6

Comment: @smathy: No, I wasn't using any version manager for ruby, I updated the answer.

Comment: If you want other details let me know.

Comment: I also tried using `rbenv global 3.2.2`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we see in the updated question, you installed rbenv, probably not fully and non-rbenv Ruby version is used

Open shell config file (looks like `~/.zshrc` in your case) and add this line to the bottom

```bash
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

You can also run this script directly in the current terminal tab

See also: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation

Comment: Why did I have to put this `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in the `~/.zshrc` file, what is it for?

I noticed that after editing the `~/.zshrc` file by adding `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`, the `$PATH` if printed at the beginning adds this:
`/Users/nameUser/.rbenv/shims`.

So wouldn't a possible solution be to add this in the `$PATH` ?

Comment: Don't try to go against the system, use the system instead. This is the recommendation of the docs, see the link in the answer body

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the accepted answer works, but it doesn't explain what your original issue is, so I just wanted to explain that.

Your PATH makes it clear here, the problem is that you've not added your homebrew path. This is usually done by the install script, but maybe you didn't run that, or maybe you changed your shell after that, or something.

What was happening was that because your homebrew `bin` directory is not in your PATH, then running `ruby` is finding the `/usr/bin/ruby` that ships with MacOS, not the `/opt/homebrew/bin/ruby` that you're installing.

You're probably going to have these issues with all homebrew installs until you fix this.

Comment: Would it be possible to see your $PATH, to understand better?

Comment: I just have my homebrew bin directory BEFORE my system directories (`/bin` and `/usr/bin`) The list is searched in order. The best idea is to redo the homebrew installation, who knows what else you're missing.